# What programmer-specific function can the old Esc do?

Tags: escaping, keyboard-layout, remap

I've recently re-remapped my tilde/backtick to Escape (that's how at least I originally learned) and put the tilde/backtick in the left-Windows key (again how I originally learned).

That floating `Esc` key way up in the NorthWest now, I've thought about mapping it a copy of F9 (for a generic SQL execution key).  Is there a suggested use for the floating Escape key that can assist a programmer?

Comment: Voting to close, because this mania of remapping half your keyboard and at the same time not knowing wha the other half does (or declaring some keys useless-obsolete) has got to stop ... IMO.

Comment: @Idigas -> current layouts are not necessarily efficient, and remapping can bring some productivity to coding.  e.g. I likely code faster in vi than anyone using arrows and mouse, keeping Escape in the prime keying area is important.

Comment: @Xepoch - current layouts are efficient enough! if you spend just half an hour thinking about the layout to save a few seconds in total in typing, and then spend one hour every day thinking about the problem ... you're doing it wrong. if one thinks fast enough, typing speed will never be the critical part ... typing speed is important only in the case when one does nothing but type.

Comment: There's also religious reasons just as there are religion in OSs not necessarily to be rehashed here.  Dvorak's another topic altogether.  The point is (and I stated in the Q) that when one /learns/ on a layout, it can be painful to switch.  Maybe I spend too much time on my keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Several ideas:

- to compile
- to execute an app
- as an escape character (ie a ^C to kill a Linux/Dos app)
- as another break key (like the one North East on your keyboard, to use your terms)
- to switch to documentation and back
- to clear cache (if web dev)
- a variety of other cleanup ideas - cache, cookies, temp files, data files, logs...

Answer (score 1):

1. To launch an often used app (like your browser)
2. To launch a launcher (like Launchy)
3. To lock your computer
4. To bring up a new email form
5. To take a screenshot
6. To show the desktop, maximize/minimize current window, etc.
7. To play/pause music
8. 2 words: "Boss key"

Answer (score 1):

How about mapping it to go to Stack Overflow?